# Logstash AWS solving code 403 trying to reconnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to push documents from local to elastic server in AWS, and when trying to do so I get 403 error and Logstash keeps on trying to establish connection with the server like so:

```
[2021-05-09T11:09:52,707][TRACE][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] Registering file input {:path=>["~/home/ubuntu/json_try/json_try.json"]}
[2021-05-09T11:09:52,737][DEBUG][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5033269f run>"}
[2021-05-09T11:09:53,441][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazonelasticsearch][main] Waiting for connectivity to Elasticsearch cluster. Retrying in 4s
[2021-05-09T11:09:56,403][INFO ][logstash.outputs.amazonelasticsearch][main] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>https://my-dom.co:8001/scans, :path=>"/"}
[2021-05-09T11:09:56,461][WARN ][logstash.outputs.amazonelasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://my-dom.co:8001/scans", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::AmazonElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '403' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://my-dom.co:8001/scans/'"}
[2021-05-09T11:09:56,849][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2021-05-09T11:09:56,853][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2021-05-09T11:09:57,444][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazonelasticsearch][main] Waiting for connectivity to Elasticsearch cluster. Retrying in 8s
.
.
.
```

I'm using the following logstash conf file:

```
input {
        file{
                type => "json"
                path => "~/home/ubuntu/json_try/json_try.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

output{
        amazon_es {
                hosts => ["https://my-dom.co/scans"]
                port => 8001
                ssl => true
                region => "us-east-1b"
                index => "snapshot-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```

Also I've exported AWS keys for the SSL to work. Is there anything I'm missing in order for the connection to succeed?

Comment: We are facing  the same issue. Did you found a solution?

Comment: In the output section I'm using 'elasticsearch' instead of 'amazon_es'. It requires the cloud_id of the aws node, cloud authentication and the target index.

Comment: I've also updated my answer right now so you can check it out and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this by using `elasticsearch` as my output plugin instead of `amazon_es`.

This usage will require `cloud_id` of the target AWS node, `cloud_auth` for it and also the target `index` in elastic for the data to be sent to. So the conf file will look something like this:

```
input {
        file{
                type => "json"
                path => "~/home/ubuntu/json_try/json_try.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

output{
        elasticsearch {
                cloud_id: "node_name:node_hash"
                cloud_auth: "auth_hash"
                index: "snapshot-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```